# FF javascript woes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Zoom.addEventListener('click', function(){$(document).ready(function(){$("#draggable").draggable({containment: '#imgContainer', scroll: false});});});
```

let me first explain the code. Zoom is a handler/button on clicking which i am enabling the dragging of an image object.

the above code works fine with Chrome but FF is finding errors. Let me quote Firebug:

```
[Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/slide/script.js :: anonymous :: line 69" data: no]
[Break on this error] Zoom.addEventListener('click', functio... '#imgContainer', scroll: false});});});
```

i am getting it to work fine in Chrome but in Firefox i cannot click the button.
pls help me out...

Comment: why would you have the ready function in a click event handler?

Comment: Maybe users tend to click something before the document has been fully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Mozilla documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.
You need to add a third parameter to the function call. Just try adding the value false, like this:

```
Zoom.addEventListener('click', function(){$(document).ready(function(){$("#draggable").draggable({containment: '#imgContainer', scroll: false});});},false);
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain why there is a ready() call in the middle of this.

Comment: Some things are better left unasked.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Zoom` is a button object you've set somewhere, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then what you need is:

```
$(function() {
  $(Zoom).click(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
      containment: '#imgContainer',
      scroll: false
    });
  });
});
```

If `Zoom` is already a jQuery object, then `Zoom.click(...` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little strange that you are doing a document ready inside the click event. It would make more sense to do it like this.

```
$(function(){//Document ready
$('zoom button').click(function(){
    $("#draggable").draggable(
        {containment: '#imgContainer', 
        scroll: false
    });
});
```

});

I think thats what you need from the code provided. Maybe that will solve the issue.